# Make require()'d variables common across node routers

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

It is common to use require() at the beginning of node apps:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
const path = require('path');
```

Also, it is good practice to split express routes among multiple files using routers:

```
app.use("/admin", require("./admin"));
app.use("/questions", require("./questions"));
```

But those router files may need the same requires used in the main app.js file, and they have to be repeated for each file. Is it any way of putting those requires in a file and sharing them among the routers and the main app.js file?

I tested imports, but it cannot assign to global scope. I tested eval, which worked as long as I use 'var' instead of 'const', but, as everybody says, "if you do with eval, there should be a more secure/efficient way to do without it".

Comment: maybe you can have a common file and import all common modules there then you can only import that file throughout your routes

Comment: You say... import into an object, not global scope? Then, I would have to use obj.fs(), obj.app(), obj.request(). I think this is going to clutter all the code. If nothing else works, maybe it is going to be the answer.

Comment: yes, that's what we've been doing so far. All common helper functions are in one file. Additionally, I don't know about express but in Koa you can auto import routes, this way, you will no longer import routes every single time.

Comment: A major point of modules is to make reusable and independently testable code that doesn't depend upon some unspecified global environment.  So, to take advantage of that, each module should `require()` or `import` its own dependencies.  Just get used to putting whatever a module needs at the top of the module even though you may feel like you're repeating yourself.  It's a requirement for good modularity.  Just get used to doing it that way.  Don't go looking for a way to ruin some of the advantages of modules to save a little typing.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to global scope is done with the **global** object:

```
//app.js:
const mylib = require("./mylib");
for (var m in mylib) global[m] = mylib[m]; //every member of the object becomes global


//mylib.js:
const fs = require("fs");
const {exec} = require('child_process');

module.exports = {
    fs,
    exec,
    
    copyFile(srcPath, dstPath) {
        fs.copyFile(srcPath, dstPath, err => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
    },
    
    deleteFile(fullPath) {
        fs.unlink(fullPath, err => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
    },
};
```

This way, it feels like you are pasting the code from module.exports into each dependent .js file, managing dependencies from the file mylib.js.